# Printing all lines that have/are duplicates of first field in Unix shell scipt

Tags: unix, printing, duplicates, field

I have a list of of semi-colon delimeted data:

```
TR=P561;dir=o;day=sa;TI=16:30;stn=south station;Line=worcester
```

I need to take this file and print out only the lines with TR values that occur more than once. I would like first occurrence and all duplicates listed.

Thanks

Comment: I am new to unix and am still trying to figure out how to go about this. From what I have seen awk would be the best way of going about it?

Comment: yes. you should take a bit of a time to learn awk, it's powerful but not difficult

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to make 2 passes on the file:

```
awk '!/TR=/ { next }         # Ignore lines that do not set TR
    {t=$0; sub( ".*TR=", "", t ); sub( ";.*", "", t ) } # Get TR value
    FNR == NR { a[t] +=1 }   # Count the number of times this value of TR seen
    FNR != NR && a[t] > 1    # print those lines whose TR value is seen more than once
' input-file input-file
```

This uses a common awk idiom of checking FNR to see which file we are using.  By passing the input-file as an argument twice, it becomes a way to run one command on the first pass, and a different command on the second.